# set ajax response to php variable

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery

I have 2 pages
javascript.js
and php.php

In my javascript.js page I am getting an ajax response like this

```
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    $j('#button').click( function () {              
       var data = {
        _method  :   'POST',
        'd[0][1]':    $j('#div').val(),
       };                                            
       $j.post('/path/file',  data,  function(response) {   
          var response = respone
       });
    });  
});
```

in my php page I want to set the variable `$response` to the ajax response. How would I do that

Comment: I think he wants to send data from the client to the server and put it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

You'll need to specific a return dataType. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/my_url',
  data: data,
  success: function( response_data ){
    alert( response_data.variable1 );
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Then in php:

```
$my_array = array(
    'variable1' => 1,
    'variable1' => 2
);
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
echo json_encode($my_array);
exit();
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In your `/path/file`:

```
<?php
$response = $_POST["your_post_variable"];
echo "'$response' has been set.";
?>
```

Cleaner JS:

```
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    $j("#button").click(function () {   
        var data = { _method: "POST", "d[0][1]", $j("#div").val() };                                            

        $j.post("/path/file",  data,  function(response){
            alert(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Php is server side, and Javascript is client side... You can't set a PHP variable from ajax on the page you've already loaded. What you can do is, call another PHP page with the relevant information, and then get generated html, and show it on your current page.

That's how Ajax works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should mention this on the odd chance you're very new to ajax or php and it's what you meant.

If the php script you're calling via ajax has a variable `$response` and all you want to do is send the contents of that variable back as your ajax response - just make sure there is no other output preceding these lines (in your php script) and use

```
echo $response;
die;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try
    echo json_encode($variable);

Also, try using jQuery's $.ajax method.